# Self Managed ELB (NLB) with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I have running EKS Cluster in AWS. Now I want to try use my own `Network Load Balancer` which were created not with AWS EKS annotations.

So my question: Is it even possible to use own NLB with EKS? If yes how can I do it? If not why it is not possible?

I've researched a lot found one opensource `kind` for EKS named as **TargetGroupBinding**, I've provided an `ARN` of my target group however than `health checks` are failing.

Answer (score 0):

For some providers it is possible, such as Tencent Kubernetes Engine per [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#aws-nlb-support) -

```
    metadata:
      name: my-service
      annotations:
        # ID of an existing load balancer
        service.kubernetes.io/tke-existed-lbid：lb-6swtxxxx
```

However this is not supported for AWS, as in the [above link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#aws-nlb-support) you can see that there is no similar annotation for AWS load balancers.

Comment: Hi, how do you think, is it possible to find a workaround?

Comment: Can you share why would you want to self-manage the ELB?

Comment: We have a couple of reasons:
1 - We need to manage the names, as our company has a naming convention for ELB, 2 - Our Route53 is setting from different account, there fore when EKS is deleting and creating the ELB, we need to compose an email to add new ELB, which is completely inconvininient. Anyway we have a lot of reasons, to mange the ELB